# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: c#, .net, connection, webexception

I'm here because I have a problem while downloading some files through ftp protocol. It's weird because it occurs occasionally and even for the same single file.

Just a precision: I'm downloading very large files (from 500 Mo to 30Go)

Here are the kind of Exceptions returned by my function : (sorry it's in french)

`System.Net.WebException: La connexion sous-jacente a été fermée : Une erreur inattendue s'est produite lors de la réception.
   à System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError()
   à System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   à System.IO.Stream.Close()
   à System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
   à System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
   à System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
   à System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   à System.Net.CommandStream.Abort(Exception e)
   à System.Net.CommandStream.CheckContinuePipeline()
   à System.Net.FtpDataStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
   à System.Net.FtpDataStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   à System.IO.Stream.Close()
   à UtilityClasses.FTP.Download(String srcDirectoryPath, String file, String destDirectoryPath)`

Here is the code used to download :

the download methods :

```
public Dictionary<string, object> Download(string srcDirectoryPath, string file, string destDirectoryPath, int attemptLimitNb, int delay)
    {
        int attemptNb = 0;
        bool downloadFailed;
        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string,object>();

        do
        { 
            attemptNb++;
            result = Download(srcDirectoryPath, file, destDirectoryPath);
            downloadFailed = result["downloadfailed"] != null;
            if (downloadFailed) Thread.Sleep((int)(1000 * delay));
        }
        while (downloadFailed && attemptNb < attemptLimitNb);
        return result;
    }

public Dictionary<string, object> Download(string srcDirectoryPath, string file, string destDirectoryPath)
    {
        Exception downloadFailed = null;
        Dictionary<string, object> result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        bool fileFound = false;

        try
        {
            if (destDirectoryPath == null || !Directory.Exists(destDirectoryPath)) throw new Exception("Download destination path does not exist");
            if (file != null && file != "")
            {
                if (file.Contains("/"))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid file name. Impossible to download");
                }

                Uri serverUri;
                if (srcDirectoryPath == null || srcDirectoryPath == "")
                {
                    serverUri = new Uri("ftp://" + this.Server + "/" + file);
                }
                else if (Regex.IsMatch(srcDirectoryPath, "^/.*$") || Regex.IsMatch(srcDirectoryPath, "^.*/$"))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Path must not start and end with '/'");
                }
                else
                {
                    serverUri = new Uri("ftp://" + this.Server + "/" + srcDirectoryPath + "/" + file);
                }

                if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp) throw new Exception("server URI Scheme does not match  FTP URI Scheme");

                if (Exists(srcDirectoryPath, file))
                {
                    fileFound = true;

                    FtpWebRequest downloadRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverUri);
                    downloadRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
                    downloadRequest.KeepAlive = false;
                    downloadRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)downloadRequest.GetResponse();

                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(destDirectoryPath, file), FileMode.Create);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
                    int read = 0;
                    try
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                            fileStream.Flush();
                        }
                        while (read != 0);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        fileStream.Close();
                        responseStream.Close();
                        response.Close();
                        throw e;
                    }
                    fileStream.Close();
                    responseStream.Close();
                    response.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webExcptn)
        {
            downloadFailed = webExcptn;
        }
        finally
        {
            result.Add("filefound", fileFound);
            result.Add("downloadfailed", downloadFailed);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

the Exists method :

```
public bool Exists(string srcPath, string elementName)
    {
        if (elementName == null || elementName == "")
        {
            return false;
        }

        Uri serverUri;
        bool res = false;

        if (srcPath == null || srcPath == "")
        {
            serverUri = new Uri("ftp://" + this.Server);
        }
        else if (Regex.IsMatch(srcPath, "^/.*$") || Regex.IsMatch(srcPath, "^.*/$"))
        {
            throw new Exception("Path must not start and end with '/'");
        }
        else
        {
            serverUri = new Uri("ftp://" + this.Server + "/" + srcPath);

        }
        if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp) throw new Exception("server URI Scheme does not match  FTP URI Scheme");

        FtpWebRequest listingRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverUri);
        listingRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
        listingRequest.KeepAlive = false;
        listingRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)listingRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string ftpElementName;
        do
        {
            ftpElementName = Path.GetFileName(streamReader.ReadLine());
            if (ftpElementName == null) break;
            else
            {
                string pattern = "^" + elementName.Replace("[", "\\[").Replace("]", "\\]").Replace("+", "[+]").Replace(".", "[.]") + "$";
                if (Regex.IsMatch(ftpElementName, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    res = true;
                }
            }
        }
        while (ftpElementName != null && !res);
        streamReader.Close();
        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return res;
    }
```

Maybe it's a timeout problem, but i don't really know. I searched for a long time for an answer but without success. Maybe some of you will have a solution.

///

EDIT : Some progress :

I have tested my code in debug mode with VS and in fact the Exception above is the consequence of a previous one. (I Couldn't know that because I only wrote the last Exception returned in a log file)

Here is the original exception :

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

The second exception is caused by this part of the Download method code :

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    fileStream.Close();
    responseStream.Close();  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    response.Close();
    throw e;
}
```

I keep on my investigations but it seems that the "timeout pb" hypothesis is the most consistent. I will try with a large timeout value tonight.

Comment: Don't apologise. The only French I remember is "Je ne parle Francais" and "Je voudrais une kilo du pomme du terre, s'il vous plais", neither of which is very useful, and probably horribly spelt :-) You've done a better job than I could in a similar situation.

Comment: Your English is pretty good actually. You've managed to ask a question that is better worded and better structured than a lot of people who visit this site and speak English as their first language.

Comment: Also, what happens if you connect with a regular FTP client to the site? Can you download the file? It sounds as if there is a connectivity error between you and the server - your code looks OK. What about if you point your code at a different FTP site (maybe a local FTP server on your machine)? Does it fail then?

Comment: Perhaps the server is closing the connection but, only sometimes, perhaps your network is unreliable

Comment: @paxdiablo The only French I remember from school is  "une biere s'il vous plait" and "ou est le toilette". Both invaluable members of my multi-lingual toolbox. What is more worrying is that I can barely remember any of this, but ZX-Spectrum BASIC and intimate details of the Apple IIcx are permanently engrained in some part of my brain.

Comment: "biere" and "toilette" are instantly recognisable to all who have experience with both ends of that particular process :-)

Comment: @mdm : it's hard to test locally, because all files are located on a distant server and if i want to test on my own computer i have to download files first, but downloading 10 Go or 20 Go takes so long time ... and i'm not sure if the file used will reproduce the exception. :(. By the way, i noticed that Exceptions occur only on very large files (> 5 Go), but not everytime.

Comment: @Hariboox: It sounds like it is a time-out as suggested in the link ScottE posted. It might be worth just firing up your FTP client and trying to download the file though - that would at least tell you whether it is a problem with your code or a problem with the server and halve the amount of investigation you will have to do.

Comment: @mdm: Ok, i'm going to try to download with FileZilla but i'm pretty sure that there is no problem with the server. but let's wait and see :)

Comment: @Hariboox, you can also create your _own_ 5G file for local testing instead of downloading. It's unlikely to be the _content_ that's causing problems, but I won't rule it out altogether :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: yes for sure ^^. But I want to test it on the original files, because i'm not completely sure that it's not their content which cause these Exceptions ... Well, it would be weird but ...

Comment: have you looked at transient error handling? I would perhaps add a retry policy this would typically resolve SQL Connection issues

Answer (score 15):

Just want to strengthen ScottE's diagnosis, and be more specific.  Timeout is most likely the issue.

Either .Net implementation of FtpWebRequest is erroneous or [the MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) has a typo, the default value of  FtpWebRequest.Timeout is not -1 (Infinite).  It is 100000 (100 seconds).

In addition there is another timeout issue.  A few tests have shown that responseStream always has a timeout value of 300000 (300 seconds). I do not know how this value is assigned. Anyways, this value needs to be modified to accommodate large files.

In summary, the solution is to set FtpWebRequest.Timeout and Stream.Timeout to a sufficiently large value.

Comment: I can confirm that the FtpWebRequest.Timeout documentation is wrong.  @Hong is right... it's 100 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good thread of things to try:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ncl/thread/47634ec2-4d40-4d3f-b075-8cc92bfa2b24

Increasing the timeout is probably a good idea in the least.

Comment: i'm going to try this solution.

Comment: I don't know that anything solved that particular problem, but it looks similar to what you're experiencing. It can get complicated with large files.

Comment: @Hariboox - I encourage you to use the 'using' construct to automatically call the dispose methods on any method that implements IDisposable. It helps prevent leaks or locks.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a symptom of an issue with the settings of your Windows Firewall.  Disabling the "Application Layer Gateway Service" in the "services" interface fixed it for me.

This thread has a lot of information:

http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-57966.html

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
request.EnableSsl = true
```